# Scraping an HTML Table with BeautifulSoup doesn't return all tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

For some reason, my code will return the value labels (e.g., 'Due Date', 'Recorded', 'Work Required' etc.) but it doesn't return the values.  For example, when I run the code, it will return "Due Date" but not "2014-Nov-27".

Making things more curious, if I adjust the code to accept a raw input of the url, the code returns everything (i.e., labels and values).

Please keep in mind that I am trying to loop through a list of urls that have the same HTML format.

HTML

```
table id="mcs-initial-abstract-grid" >
        <tr class="mci-grid-row-header">
            <th >
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>SOME STRING</td>
                        <td>SOME INTEGER   </td>
                        <td>SOME STRING</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr class="mci-gridview-alternate">
                        <td style="width:25%"><strong>Due Date:</strong></td>
                        <td style="width:20%">2014-Nov-27</td>
                        <td style="width:20%"><strong>Recorded:</strong></td>
                        <td style="width:35%">2015-Nov-7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td><strong>Work Required:</strong></td>
                        <td>$20</td>
                        <td><strong>Variable:</strong></td>
                        <td>2015-Nov-25 14:20</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

My Code:

```
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import urllib

url = 'enter url here'
r = requests.get(url)
html_content = r.text
soup = bs(html_content, 'html5lib')
for tags in soup.find_all('table', id='mcs-initial-abstract-grid'):
    for tbody in tags.find_all('tbody'):
        for tr in tbody.find_all('tr', {'class':'mci-gridview-alternate'} ):
            for td in tr.find_all('td'):
                print td.text
```

Comment: Perhaps `html5lib` is generous in supplying missing tags; however, I notice that `tbody` is missing from the HTML that's listed with the question.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely culprit is `tbody`. This is one of the "special" tags that are [usually generated by browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements). And, since you are getting the page source with `requests` - there is no real browser involved, you are not gonna get `tbody` in the `html_content`.

And, if eliminating `tbody` from your HTML parsing logic does not help, try [other parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) - `html.parser` or `lxml` instead of `html5lib`.

Comment: I have removed the tbody tag and received a very similar result.  I have also tried 'lxml' and 'html.parser', with no luck.  Also, when I convert the code to prompt for a raw_input for the url, the data are returned.  This is great but I need to loop through a list of urls.