# css - immediate 1st tr 2nd td not working

Tags: css

I'm not sure why below is not working.  I'm trying to apply `color:red` style on the `outer table`'s first `tr` and second `td`.

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px black solid;
}

#outerTable>tr:first-child>td:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="outerTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      outer table 1st tr 1st td
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            inner table 1st tr 1st td
          </td>
          <td>
            inner table 1tr 2nd td
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      outer table 1st tr 2nd td -- Only want this Red
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the DOM there is a `tbody` tag.
Change your code to

```
#outerTable > tbody > tr:first-child > td:nth-child(2) {
```

```css
table, tr, td {
border:1px black solid;  
}

#outerTable > tbody > tr:first-child > td:nth-child(2) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<table id="outerTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      outer table 1st tr 1st td
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            inner table 1st tr 1st td
          </td>
          <td>
            inner table 1tr 2nd td
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
    </td>
    <td>
      outer table 1st tr 2nd td -- Only want this Red
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [Further reading as to why `tbody`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements) is automatically generated

Comment: @justinw This is rather educational for styling tables. I never knew that `tbody` must be included in styling even when it is omitted in the `html`

Answer (score 0):

The selector should be `#outerTable > tbody > tr:first-of-type > td:nth-child(2)`

```css
table, tr, td {
border:1px black solid;  
}

#outerTable > tbody > tr:first-of-type > td:nth-child(2) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<table id="outerTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      outer table 1st tr 1st td
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            inner table 1st tr 1st td
          </td>
          <td>
            inner table 1tr 2nd td
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
    </td>
    <td>
      outer table 1st tr 2nd td -- Only want this Red
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.colorRed {
  color: red;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<table id="outerTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      outer table 1st tr 1st td
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            inner table 1st tr 1st td
          </td>
          <td>
            inner table 1tr 2nd td
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="colorRed">
      outer table 1st tr 2nd td -- Only want this Red
    </td>
```

It is because you didn't specify what part should only be colored red.
Add class name on the td that you wanted the text to have color red.

```
<table id="outerTable">
<tr>
<td>
  outer table 1st tr 1st td
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>  
        inner table 1st tr 1st td
      </td>
      <td>
        inner table 1tr 2nd td
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>  
</td>
<td class="colorRed">
  outer table 1st tr 2nd td -- Only want this Red
</td>
```

In CSS add this:

```
.colorRed{
 color: red;
}
```