# Suddenly importxml #n/a error import content is empty appear

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I have some problem to use importXML function in my spreadsheet.
I used function 'importxml' and it was worked! Also, it stacked data well (with GA).
But some day, a function error appeared #n/a(error import content is empty).
I have no clue why this error happens.

Sample Url:
http://www.yes24.com/searchcorner/Search?query=9788998599362
(for reference, it's a Korean website)

Xpath

```
//p[contains(@class,'goods_rating')]/text()[1]
```

I change Xpath to '*' and parsing **head** tag inside text and it's working!
I think the web site doesn't block the google spreadsheet function.

But with no reason(or any clue) importxml cannot parse **body** tag inside text anymore. It just prints #n/a error.

I also checked with Chrome Xpath helper to Xpath Syntax. It could track the text, there seems no problem.

How can I fix this problem?

P.S:red box is Xpath target

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### **Try**

`=importxml("http://www.yes24.com/searchcorner/Search?query=9788998599362","//*[@id='schMid_wrap']/div[3]/div[2]/table/tr[1]/td[2]/p[4]/text()[1]")`

### **How I got this**

When you visit the page,

- Right-click on the element you want you import, and select **Inspect**
- In the Inspect pane, if you do not see the element, open the collapsible arrows on the highlighted section until you see your element.
- Right-click on the element, Copy, Copy XPath
- Paste XPath in to the second parameter of the *`=importxml()`*
- There will be double quotes (`" "`) just after the *`@id=`*, you will need to change them to single quotes so the *`=importxml()`* includes it into the string.
- Test it, if it doesn't work, remove `/tbody`

See: [Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements)
to see why `/tbody` was there in the first place.

### Note

I had trouble with this XPath too, I ended up just changing the quotes and deleting the stuff in **Bold** and it worked for me.

`//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/span/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[18]/article/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span`