# unexpected auto-insertion of a tbody element: table is not row.parentElement

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Check this simple table:

```js
const table = document.getElementById("table");

table.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    const affectedRow = e.target.closest('tr');
    table.removeChild(affectedRow);
  }
});
```

```html
<table border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>row A</td>
    <td><button>delete row</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row B</td>
    <td><button>delete row</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row C</td>
    <td><button>delete row</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Trying to remove a row using `table.removeChild(affectedRow)` gives me

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

Is using a `tbody` element *mandatory*?

Why are browsers auto-inserting a `tbody` element? I checked on validator.w3.org and omitting a `tbody` tag seems valid HTML.

How do I remove the row **without using** `HTMLTableElement.prototype.deleteRow(index)`, using only `HTMLElement.prototype` methods and properties?

Comment: Firefox 68 also inserts a `tbody` element

Answer (score 2):

You can check to see if the table has a tbody element beneath it, and if so, delete rows from underneath that element instead:

```js
const table = document.getElementById("table");
const tbody = (table.firstElementChild.nodeName == 'TBODY' ? table.firstElementChild : table);

table.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    const affectedRow = e.target.closest('tr');
    tbody.removeChild(affectedRow);
  }
});
```

```html
<table border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>row A</td>
    <td><button>delete row</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row B</td>
    <td><button>delete row</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row C</td>
    <td><button>delete row</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way `table.tBodies[0].removeChild`

why?

tbody, thead and tfoot are inserted by all browsers even the champion IE does that, its the W3c spec.

> The HTML Table Body element (tbody) encapsulates a set of table rows (tr elements), indicating that they comprise the body of the table (table) similarly the header and footer of the table.

Comment: Thanks, but how about my other questions? I'd like to understand what's going on.

Comment: does this answer your query?

Comment: As my question is a duplicate, I'm not going to pick an answer.

Comment: as long as it satisfies the curiosity bro :)

Answer (score 1):

Many browsers add a `<tbody>` element to HTML tables, if one doesn't exist. You can read more about why on this post: [Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements)

`removeChild()` only removes children, not descendants. So if a `<tbody>` exists then the `<tr>` you're trying to remove is a child of `<tbody>`, and not a child of the `<table>` element.

You could do:

```
document.querySelector("#table tbody").removeChild(affectedRow);
```

Comment: I see this came unexpected for you, too. I'd really like to understand if this is how it is supposed to behave and if so, why. Will I have to check whether in the browser the code is run in it has inserted a `tbody`?

Comment: @connexo See this post as to why browsers do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements