# Python xPath looping for TR table rows but object empty

Tags: python, xpath

Hi we are running this code and it is driving my crazy

- we capture a data table in `table` this works
- then grab all th and it's text in `sizes` this works
- then we want to grab all underlying rows in TR; and after loop over columns in rows : **does not work!** the `color_rows` object is always empty .. but when testing with xpath in the browser it does! work ... why? how?

**My question is**: how can I grab the tbody/tr's?

Expected flow

1. loop over TR's
2. Access, TR 1 by 1, get 1st TD
3. Get all TD's data that have class form-control

   ```
    table = response.xpath('//div[@class="content"]//table[contains(@class,"table")]')
    sizes = table.xpath('./thead//th/text()').getall()[1:] #works!
    color_rows = table.xpath('./tbody/tr') #does not work! object empty
    for color_row in color_rows:
        color = color_row.xpath('/td[1]/b/text()').get().strip()
        print(color)
        stocks = color_row.xpath('/td/div[input[@class="form-control"]]/div//text()').getall()
        for size, stock in zip(sizes, stocks)
   ```

Our html data looks like this

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="ctl00_cphCEShop_colColore" class="text-left" colspan="2">Colore</th>
                <th>S</th>
                <th>M</th>
                <th>L</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="x">
                <b>White</b>
                <input type="hidden" name="data" value="3230/201">
            </td>
            <td id="avail">
                Avail:
            </td>
            <td id="1">
                <div>
                    <input name="cell" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="text-center">179</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="2">
                <div>
                    <input name="cell" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="text-center">360</div>
                </div>
            </td>
etc etc
```

Comment: Given your sample html, what's your expected output?

Comment: Expected is ito
1. loop over TR's
2. Per TR get first /TD
3. Get all other TD's that have class form-control

Comment: I understand, but after all the "get"s are gotten and you issue a `print()` command, what exactly is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently tbody tags are often omitted in HTML but aded by the browser.

In this case there was no (real) body tag making the xpath object miss!

And hence the troubles with xpath (if you really think the tbody tag is there)

[Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements)