# How can I get the body of a table using document.querySelector when there is more than one table on a page?

Tags: javascript

I have three Bootstrap tables on a page (all of which are of `class=table` and none of which currently has an ID).

I have the following JavaScript function which I want to use to build a table:

```
function createTable(data) {
    const tableBody = document.querySelector('tbody');

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = `<td>${data[i].id}</td>
        <td>${data[i].firstName}</td>
        <td>${data[i].lastName}</td>
        <td>${data[i].age}</td>`
        tableBody.append(tr)
    }
}
```

Two of the tables on my page have a `<body>` tag and only one of the tables has a `<tbody>` tag.

**Question:**  in the above function, should I use an ID for `document.querySelector`?  Or, will it "know" that it should only look at the only table that has `<tbody>`?

Comment: Your selector cares nothing about tables. It's going to return the first tbody element it finds, regardless of its context.

Comment: FYI, a body element is invalid inside a table. A document may only have one.

Comment: @isherwood I'm pretty sure that's a typo for `<tbody>`

Comment: `querySelector` finds the **first** element that matches. Either use a more specific CSS selector string than `tbody` (Google for how to find the first element of type with querySelector), or use querySelectorAll to get multiple matches and figure it out in a loop

Comment: I think the thing the OP is concerned about is whether the browser automaticlly adds `<tbody>` to tables that don't have it, like they do when fixing up other HTML errors. I don't think this is a case where they do it.

Comment: @isherwood I misread and thought they said "two don't have a `<body>`"

Comment: [All `table` elements have at least one `tbody` element silently added if not present in the source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/938083/215552), so your selector is likely to always return the first `tbody` of the first `table` element in source order.

Comment: Coming back to my original question, should I then add an ID to the table (`<table id="my-table" class="table">`), and also amend the `querySelector` to `document.querySelector('my-table')`?

Comment: So use a better selector. Use an id or class or something of a parent.