# Javascript handling checkbox array in HTML table

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML table that consists of up to 25 rows.
A typical row:

```js
function chkcountfn(required, el_id) {
  let memid = getid(el_id);
  let dateElement = "awarddate_" + memid;
  let datestr = document.getElementById(dateid).innerHTML
  let count = 0;

  // now need to go through all checkboxes with id of el_id and count those checked
  if (count >= required) {
    alert("Required number of skills acheived");
    if (datestr.length === 0) {
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
      }
      if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
      }
      today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
      document.getElementById(dateid).innerHTML = today;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById(dateid).innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function getid(str) {
  var fields = str.split('_');
  var id = fields[1];
  return id;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="128" name="name">Mike Starmer</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_128[0]' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_128[1]' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_128[2]' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_128[3]' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_128[4]' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_128[5]' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_128[6]' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_128[7]' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_128[8]' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='chk_128[9]' /></td>
      <td id="passdate_128"> </td>
      <td id="awarddate_128"></td>
      <td hidden id="memid_128">128</td>
      <td hidden id="classid_128">7</td>
      <td hidden id="badgeid_128">7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I should add the table is constructed using PHP echo calls,

I am trying to add an `onchange` or `onclick` event to each checkbox that will count all the checked checkboxes in a row and show an alert if more than 80% are checked.

I have tried web searches on Javascript onchange and onclick functions, but all seem to relate to single checkbox.

So far I have come up with the following:

1. for each checkbox add an onclick or onchange action that passes the checkbox id to the called function **onclick="chkcountfn(8,this.id)"** the 8 is the number of items needed to have checked.
2. the function takes the passed id and then parses all checkboxes with that id counting those that are checked. If that number is =>80% then pop-up an alert, and write current date back to the rows "passdate_x".

To be honest I have checked the date substitution, which I found by searching this site, but have not managed to test anything else.

This is my first attempt at HTML/Javascript, and as you can see I am stuck on the looping through the checkboxes part and would also appreciate any helpful comments on what I have/am doing wrong. Also is it better to use an onchange or onclick event as I have been led to understand there are problems with some iPhones as they don't associate checkboxes and click events.

Comment: I made a snippet of the code you provided - both the HTML and JavaScript have/had syntax issues.  I only provided a rough table/tbody but you  should update that with proper ids, classes etc.  The JavaScript still has the provided syntax issue(s)

Comment: _"the function takes the passed id and then parses all checkboxes with that id"_ - IDs must be unique; you can not have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: what do you mean by 80% ?   is that refer to one row or the entire table ?

Comment: While valid here in 2024 I would suggest you NOT use an id starting with a number/digit as it will make CSS more challenging to construct.  Ref for id: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Perhaps add a second row to the snippet since from your description it should have a new unique set of ids.

Comment: I don't know what happened biut for some reason the IDs of the checkboxes have been changed from id= to name=.

Comment: 80% refers to 80% of the checkboxes in the row.  With regard to the IDs on the same row having the same ID e.g. chk_xxx{x}  I understood you could have arrays of IDs - have I read this wrong? Thanks for the advice about the ID being a nueric.

Comment: is there a form somewhere ?, if this check boxes data is sent to a server you need to use name attributes everyxhere,

Comment: FWIW I would suggest you NOT put `[28]` in and id attribute so you don't have to escape those `[]` in some instances in code. Prefer something like `myidname-28` or `myidname_28` (not my choice) or `myIdName28` etc. so for yours `chk_128[3]` I would suggest something like `choice-128-3]`  OR just make them all classes that represent the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way to achieve your goal of only allowing 80% of the checkboxes on each row to be selected would be to simply get the boxes within the `tr` that had a checkbox update and compare the total number of checkboxes against the number which have been checked.

Using this pattern you avoid the need for any convoluted code to target `id` attributes dynamically (which should be unique, just FYI) and also works for an infinite number of rows in your HTML.

Here's a working example:

```js
const checkboxChangeHandler = e => {
  const cb = e.target;
  const row = cb.closest('tr');
  const checkboxes = row.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  const checked = Array.from(checkboxes).filter(cb => cb.checked);
  const maxAllowed = Math.floor(checkboxes.length * 0.8); // or Math.ceil()
  
  if (checked.length > maxAllowed) {
    cb.checked = false;
    console.log('too many checkboxes selected on this row');
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(cb => cb.addEventListener('change', checkboxChangeHandler));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="128" name="name">Mike Starmer</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128[0]" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128[1]" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128[4]" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128[5]" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128[6]" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128[7]" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128[8]" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128[9]" /></td>
    <td id="passdate_128"> </td>
    <td id="awarddate_128"></td>
    <td hidden id="memid_128">128</td>
    <td hidden id="classid_128">7</td>
    <td hidden id="badgeid_128">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="129" name="name">Mike Starmer</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129[0]" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129[1]" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129[2]" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129[3]" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129[4]" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129[5]" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129[6]" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129[7]" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129[8]" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129[9]" /></td>
    <td id="passdate_129"> </td>
    <td id="awarddate_129"></td>
    <td hidden id="memid_129">129</td>
    <td hidden id="classid_129">7</td>
    <td hidden id="badgeid_129">7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the calculation includes the disabled checkboxes. This can easily be amended if they should be ignored.

Comment: Probably need the second row `<td id="128"` to be `<td id="129"` LOL looks like we are in a post race :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thanks - missed that one. I was tempted to remove the `id` completely, and make the `name` consistent, eg. `name="chk_x[]"`, but I'll leave that for the OP to investigate

Comment: Yes for all this IMHO classes would be better

Comment: Related, and my logic for adding the tbody to the snippet I created for the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/q/938083/125981

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to mark this as the answer. I hadn't found any references to the row.closest before - guess I'm going to have a lot of reading/learning - seems to me javascript is going to be much more convoluted to learn than PHP!

Comment: @rte76 `seems to me javascript is going to be much more convoluted to learn than PHP!` -> This is normal: JavaScript is a language that integrates interface management, which is not the case for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical use case for event delegation.

...and rather than using an alert, it is preferable to use the one provided for managing HTML5 forms.
Otherwise, if this is indeed a form, then this HTML code is not good.

```js
const myTable = document.querySelector('#my-table');

myTable.onchange = ({target:elm}) =>  // global change for event delegation
  {
  if (!elm.matches('input[type="checkbox"]')) return  // get only changes on checkboxes elements

  let rowChkBx = [...elm.closest('tr').querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')].reduce((a,chkbx)=>
    {
    a.count++;
    if (chkbx.checked) a.checked++
    return a;
    },{count:0,checked:0});

  if ( rowChkBx.checked > (rowChkBx.count * .8))
    {
    elm.checked = false;
    alert('the 80% quota has already been reached!');
    }
  }
```

```css
html {
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 14px;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td data-name="name">Mike Starmer 128</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128-0" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128-1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128-2" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128-3" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128-4" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128-5" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128-6" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128-7" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128-8" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_128-9" /></td>
    <td id="passdate_128"> </td>
    <td id="awarddate_128"></td>
    <td hidden id="memid_128">128</td>
    <td hidden id="classid_128">7</td>
    <td hidden id="badgeid_128">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="129" name="name">Mike Starmer 129</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129-0" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129-1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129-2" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129-3" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129-4" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129-5" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129-6" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129-7" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129-8" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk_129-9" /></td>
    <td id="passdate_129"> </td>
    <td id="awarddate_129"></td>
    <td hidden id="memid_129">129</td>
    <td hidden id="classid_129">7</td>
    <td hidden id="badgeid_129">7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I simply eliminated all those id's - put them back IF you need them for posting but this avoids all the id hassle if you don't need them.

This IS more verbose than it might be but I left it that way to illustrate each  think in the code.

Study each part but I did put the constants in an object `const myCheckFun = {` then used them all from there to avoid duplication.

I used the options on the date local string; look that up here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```js
/* do this! */
function getFormattedDate() {
  // we use the uk local because is is ddmmyyyy :)
  return new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-uk', {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
    day: "numeric"
  })
}

function checkCount(row, isEnough, elId) {
  let memid = elId;
  let dateElement = row.querySelector('.awarddate')
  // we passed this from the caller change handler
  if (isEnough) {
    alert("Required number of skills acheived");
    //dateElement.textContent = getDateString();
    dateElement.textContent = getFormattedDate();
  } else {
    dateElement.textContent = "";
  }
}

// created this object just to store some things being re-used and not have lots of globals:
const myCheckFun = {
  containerSelector: 'table.check-fun-container',
  rowSelector: 'tbody tr[data-identifier]',
  checkSelector: 'input[type="checkbox"][data-check-identifier]',
  checkedSelector: 'input[type="checkbox"][data-check-identifier]:checked',
  idRowElems: [],
  //  idList: [],
  minimumPercent: 80
};

//assumed 1 container only
myCheckFun.idParent = document.querySelector(myCheckFun.containerSelector);
// get all the TR's that have a data-identifier value (on row in the HTML)
myCheckFun.idRowElems = myCheckFun.idParent.querySelectorAll(myCheckFun.rowSelector);

function handleChangeEvent(event) {
  const elem = event.target;
  // the delegate row where event is attached
  const cbrow = event.currentTarget;
  const rowID = cbrow.dataset.identifier;
  if (elem.type === "checkbox" && elem.dataset && elem.dataset.checkIdentifier) {
    const allCbxs = cbrow.querySelectorAll(myCheckFun.checkSelector);
    const checkedCbxs = cbrow.querySelectorAll(myCheckFun.checkedSelector);
    // console.log(allCbxs.length, checkedCbxs.length);
    // simple calculation from ^^
    const cboxPct = checkedCbxs.length / allCbxs.length;
    const isEnough = cboxPct >= (myCheckFun.minimumPercent / 100);
    //console.log('ID:', rowID, 'PCT:', cboxPct, isEnough);
    checkCount(cbrow, isEnough, rowID);
  }
}

function setupObject(rows) {
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    // add a change delegate to the row - now we can listen for changes
    // with one listener not 10 for each row
    row.addEventListener("change", handleChangeEvent);
  });
}

setupObject(myCheckFun.idRowElems);
```

```html
<table class="check-fun-container">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-identifier="128">
      <td name="name">Mike Starmer</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='0' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='1' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='2' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='3' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='4' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='5' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='6' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='7' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='8' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='9' /></td>
      <td class="passdate"></td>
      <td class="awarddate"></td>
      <td hidden class="memid">128</td>
      <td hidden class="classid">7</td>
      <td hidden class="badgeid">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-identifier="129">
      <td name="name">Willie Bear</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='0' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='1' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='2' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='3' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='4' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='5' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='6' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='7' /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='8' checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' data-check-identifier='9' /></td>
      <td class="passdate"></td>
      <td class="awarddate"></td>
      <td hidden class="memid">129</td>
      <td hidden class="classid">7</td>
      <td hidden class="badgeid">7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - I had already accepted Rory's answer, but will ry to understand how your answer works, as Javascript is "something new" to me. Also thanks for the pointer to the toLocaleDateString as it is something I hadn't even thought of looking for.

Comment: Sure, you can accept whichever answer best helps you; I don't get worked up on reputation but more to provide alternatives and in this case the part of your question to apply the date as a date formatted as you specify.  Once you understand the basics (really understand them) of this prototypical language (ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) it makes use easier as you work with it more.